# Reactive forms / Passing data between components using provider services.- Application breaks during REFRESH/RELOAD

Tags: angular

My reactive form receives data from the parent component via data service....All fine except page reload where it breaks totally because of the loss of dependency on the parent component(Unable to read the data.). I know there are multiple approaches for passing data b/n components...Can somebody suggest  me which would be the best in terms of surviving scenarios like what i am facing , also in terms of performance n other aspects...

CODE:

Parent component constructor:

```
constructor( private _reporterdata: DataStorage);
```

Save the data to service:

```
this._reporterdata.data = selectedReporter; //before moving away from component.
```

Child component constructor:

```
 constructor(private _reporterdata: DataStorage)
```

I use **_reporterdata.data** for my reactive form. It breaks when i reload the child component.
Thanks in advance...ASJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using service `private _reporterdata:DataStorage`, here it stores the data in which way depends on that.

Whenever you are using a service on refresh the service data is emptied and then there is no data present in the variables of the services.

> So that's why you don't have the data present on page refresh

There are different approaches for it in the service you can store the data into many ways so that on page reload the data is maintained

1. Local storage
2. Session storage
3. Etc.

Store the values in local storage from the service and on page refresh get the data from service which gets it from the local storage

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to retain the data after browser refresh then you need to use web storage (local storage etc). But if you want to sense the data in different components which is the main aim of SPA then we have different approaches in Angular

- Use of subjects.
- Output decorator
  Please clarify what exactly you want.

Comment: Hi...mine was the first case where i want to retain the data....Thanks.